# Kernel keeps dying when I try to import pipeline from transformers

Tags: python, pandas, pipeline, huggingface-transformers

I want to import pipeline from transformers and i had already installed transformers using '!pip install transformers'. But now when I put 'from transformers import pipeline' my kernel keeps on dying. Failry new to coding so help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide any more information about what is happening?  Are you getting an error message?  Try running it from a console if it is crashing in a way that you can't see the error.

Comment: @orh im not able  to post image but the error says 'The HDF5 header files do not match the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked. data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.'

Comment: are you on apple silicon by any chance?

Comment: Yes I have the same problem with apple Silicon M1 pro 14