# Jupyter kernel dies when importing pipeline function from transformers class on Mac OS

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, huggingface-transformers

I'm unable to import pipeline function of transformers class as my jupyter kernel keeps dying. Tried on transformers-4.15.0 and 4.16.2. Anyone faced this issue?

I tried importing the class in a new notebook as you can see in the image and it keeps killing the kernel.

[image: Jupyter Lab Screenshot]

Comment: can you show the code you used and the output ?

Comment: I've updated it in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.

[image]

You could try creating a fresh conda environment and reinstalling the app.

You could also try using jupyterlab instead of jupyter-notebook.

Are you on Mac OS? I couldn't get it to run at first using `conda install transformers` my jupyterlab kept hanging as well.

Then I did this, `conda install -c huggingface transformers` and here is the result.

[image]

It works fine for me on linux and Mac now.

Comment: Tried creating fresh conda environment but didn't help. Already using JupyterLab.
I saw another person facing the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589297/kernel-keeps-dying-when-i-try-to-import-pipeline-from-transformers

Is this related to Apple silicon by any chance?

Comment: @AngadChandhok hey I updated my answer, take a look, I think there a problem with the normal version on Mac OS you have to use the one from the hugging face channel.

Comment: @AngadChandhok are you on Mac OS ?

Comment: yes, MacOS on Macbook pro 2021

Comment: @AngadChandhok look at my answer, I added a command for Mac OS, it should work after you do that

Comment: @AngadChandhok conda install -c huggingface transformers

Comment: I just tried the steps you mentioned above and restarted jupyterlab as well. Transformers version shows 4.11.3 but it still doesn't resolve it for me

Comment: Create a new environment and try it again, install this first

Comment: Thank you! creating a new environment helped. The command runs now

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Mac with a M1 silicon chip, you could try reinstalling transformers through huggingface using `conda install -c huggingface transformers`. It worked for me with Python 3.9 in a notebook when i had the same issue.