# Jupyter Kernel dies when importing from transformers class on Mac (M1) OS

Tags: python, machine-learning, import, environment, sentiment-analysis

[image: dead kernel]

I am trying to run the following line of code for a class project but cannot get it to work! I have seen a similar question here: [Jupyter kernel dies when importing pipeline function from transformers class on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024254/jupyter-kernel-dies-when-importing-pipeline-function-from-transformers-class-on)
but i have tried to install via transformers class and this still does not affect the import, although I was quite unsure how the 'new environment' concept worked. any help would be much appreciated!

[image: installation of transformers class successful via hugging face]

tried to complete as seen in other solutions but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Its the same issue I mention here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132/65449643#65449643 , problem is you installed libraries for the wrong architecture (x86_64 or ARM) while it is running in the other architecture (ARM or x86_64).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy even though I'm not installing tensorflow?

Comment: Yes, its not tensorflow specific, this issue of mixing ARM/x86_64 libraries happens to any python library that uses a native library inside of its code. TensorFlow is just an example of it (libtensorflow.so inside the tensorflow python package).

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall tensorflow - this worked for me